# How to include ProviderName in the command that gets event logs in the past ten hours

Tags: windows, powershell, get-winevent

```
$A = @{}
$A.Add("StartTime", ((Get-Date).AddHours(-10)))
$A.Add("EndTime", (Get-Date))
$A.Add("LogName", "System")
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $A|Select TimeCreated, ProviderName, Message|FL)
```

The above commands will get all "**System**" event logs in the past 10 hours. However, I want to get only the event logs of "**Microsoft-Windows-WindowsUpdateClient**" in the past 10 hours. I tried the following line, which caused an error.

```
$A.Add("LogName", "System" ; "ProviderName", "*UpdateClient")
```

How should I include "ProviderName" in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add another key and value using `Add` method

```
$A.Add("ProviderName", "*UpdateClient")
```